# Oracle 11 IMPDP Table Exists but gets Does Not Exist Error

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, datapump

I'm running in to a weird problem with IMPDP and Oracle DB version 11.2.0.4.0 where I have a table in the destination schema that does indeed exist, but IMPDP thinks it doesn't. See this entry from the import log file:

> Starting "EXPORT_USER"."SYS_IMPORT_TABLE_01":  export_user/********
>   directory=EXPORT_DIRECTORY
>   dumpfile=SMARTCLOUDCONSOLE_OWNER_20170830.dmp
>   TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=APPEND DATA_OPTIONS=SKIP_CONSTRAINT_ERRORS
>   REMAP_SCHEMA=SMARTCLOUDCONSOLE_OWNER:MIKETESTCONSOLE_OWNER
>   TABLES=SMARTCLOUDCONSOLE_OWNER.ACCOUNTDEPLOYMENTLINKS QUERY="WHERE
>   account_id = (select account_id from accounts where lower(guid) =
>   '#####')"
>
> Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
>
> Table "MIKETESTCONSOLE_OWNER"."ACCOUNTDEPLOYMENTLINKS" exists. Data
>   will be appended to existing table but all dependent metadata will be
>   skipped due to table_exists_action of append
>
> Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
>
> ORA-31693: Table data object
>   "MIKETESTCONSOLE_OWNER"."ACCOUNTDEPLOYMENTLINKS" failed to load/unload
>   and is being skipped due to error: ORA-00942: table or view does not
>   exist

We are using VPDs such that the `_owner` user owns all of the objects, so I don't think it's a problem of ownership. And it seems like it figures out that the table exists from the second line there `Table "MIKETESTCONSOLE_OWNER"."ACCOUNTDEPLOYMENTLINKS" exists.` but then when it proceeds it fails with `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

What might be wrong with my use of IMPDP?

Comment: i think it may be complaining about accounts table in your query.

Comment: Just previously to running this impdp statement, I ran one to import the accounts table (needed different queries because the schema differs too much), and that works just fine... Do you think I need to preface that query with the destination schema (e.g. `select account_id from MIKETESTCONSOLE_OWNER.accounts where...`)?

Comment: only if it is in a different schema, if it is in your own schema (to which you are importing into). OR see if the user running impdp has permissions.

Comment: Turns out impdp doesn't like prefacing tables with the destination schema like that, and it didn't matter anyways because it's in the same schema. I'll have to see what I can dig up about the permissions.

Comment: So if I connect to sqlplus as this `export_user` I can run `select * from miketestconsole_owner.accounts;` and it returns me the data I'm expecting. But I can't run just a `select * from accounts;`, as that throws the same ORA-00942 error... I'll try prefacing the table with the schema in the QUERY clause again so I can get the error, but impdp didn't seem to like that any better. Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: Can you try changing TABLES=SMARTCLOUDCONSOLE_OWNER.ACCOUNTDEPLOYMENTLINKS  to TABLES=ACCOUNTDEPLOYMENTLINKS  and see if it helps? i think this may be causing issue with remap_schema you have

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a permission issue. As Raj pointed out make sure that export_user has select privilege for the accounts table. Which it will have if it owns the table. Also make sure that it has select, insert, update and delete for MIKETESTCONSOLE_OWNER.ACCOUNTDEPLOYMENTLINKS and all of the tables in that schema. If tables are added over time, you probably need to add grants.